# Modify div when it scrolls through other div

Tags: jquery, html, highlight, viewport

I have a long horizontal page like this:

```
<div id="viewport"></div>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

Div **Viewport** is positioned absolutely on the left edge of the screen. The rest of the divs are floated horizontally.

What I want to accomplish is that when each of the floating divs are scrolled into the viewport div, they change some css properties (like opacity). I want the div to become "active" or highlighted as it is scrolled by.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you could make your own event handler to do this but you could just check in the code that moves the divs if they are inside the viewport and apply a highlight class using the jQuery .animate() function quite easily, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/sRhJH/24/

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Is there a way to have it so that only one div is highlighted at once, rather than having it fade out only after its left the veiwport?

Comment: Another question after working with the code you provided: How can I make it so the scroll bars activate the div highlight, not the buttons created in that example?

Comment: Well I have a scrollbar. My document is about 6000px wide. I just want to use that, and when my divs are scrolled near the left edge of the screen (or in the viewport) I want them the highlight. I don't want to attach any other scrollbars.

Comment: You can play around with the if statements to make them appear when an item is fully in the box, http://jsfiddle.net/sRhJH/25/ in this I've just removed the + width check which means a soon as the item is outside the div

Comment: you might be able to use fixed on the viewport and use the .scroll event in jquery to check and update the divs

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve that. Could you elaborate or simplify your code a little bit? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `offset()` method will give you an element's position within the document.

Use it, along with `width()`, to determine the location of the viewport div:

```
var vp = $('#viewport'),
    vp_offset = vp.offset(),  // has x and y properties
    vp_width = vp.width();
```

Then, hook into the `window`'s scroll event to get position data for the page elements:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // use similar offset code used above for determining the location of the 
    // scrolling moving divs
});
```